# Read from resx file at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a list of strings I'm keeping a `.resx` file that I would like to use to populate a list during runtime.  I was planning on using a `ResXResourceReader`.  I'm not sure what the filepath to my resource file would be, but following the directions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxdatanode.aspx), an exception is throwing saying that it can't find the `.resx` file in the bin directory corresponding to my selected build target.  Is my resource file somewhere else that I can access during run time or do I need to change the build action on this resource file so it appears somewhere that I can reach at run time?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is never not a mistake.  The .resx format is an implementation detail for .NET projects.  The only thing it is good for is to get it converted to the .resource format as quickly as possible and add it to the metadata of an assembly.  Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream() provides the low-level interface, ResourceManager is the high-level view that's aware of localization.  Taking a dependency on program build details is never not a mistake.  And of course you can't find the file, it lives inside folders that are part of your project.  You are not going to deploy your project.

Comment: I'm only trying to keep a rarely changing list of strings obfuscated from the rest of the implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In source explorer right click the file and select properties. There is a setting called "Copy to Output Directory" it typically defaults to do not copy. Change it to copy always or copy if newer.

On a side note, I don't think you're using the resx as intended. I believe that is more used as a compile time resource, you can access the values in the file in a static manner in your source. Instead, if you want an extra, more dynamic resource file, you should just add a flat file to the project (with data in your preferred format) and set copy to output directory to copy if newer.

EDIT: After reading the comments I want to reiterate that this is an abuse of the resx and not it's intended use. I highly recommend using the suggestion provided in the second paragraph (personally I would use a text file with json and parse it into objects uses json.net's generic deserialize method), the first bit applies to all types of files and is just a way for you to interact with the build script (in this case the csproj file) via Visual Studio's GUI.

Comment: I agree with the second paragraph here.  The .resx should be used in a static manner.  It's really helpful when i18n-ing your application.  Add a separate file to your application and use a reader of sorts.

Comment: @impr0t thank you for the reinforcement as I don't use those much but seemed to remember accessing values in it as if they were global constants. The first paragraph is not my advice, but is what I believe the OP is looking for.

Comment: I jumped to using a `.resx` file because it was going to be a static resource.  I didn't intend to change the contents of the resource file during runtime, just be able to use the strings there during runtime.  I was kind of following the pattern that Android seemed to follow back when I was working in that environment.  Is using a json file really that much better than using a resource file?

Comment: @JakeSmith I would personally say yes because you could have a file that is nothing more than a json array and then deseriailize to an array of strings in 1 line with type safety. With the resx file you either have to reference each string in the list explicitly or make the value a delimited list which you then have to spit. Basically, it would work but it's not as elegant and it might throw off other C# developers who later maintain or work with the code.